# Radio button in list view

Tags: android

I am showing list of sting in list view formate, i used default list view and placed a radio button by using `simple_list_item_single_choice`. But this shown the Radio button in right side, i want to display the radio button in left side. is that any possible to show the radio button in left side using default list view

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`simple_list_item_single_choice.xml` use `CheckedTextView` class

Here is the  `simple_list_item_single_choice.xml`

```
 <CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
   />
```

You need to create a custom xml for your need and use a `CheckBox` to achieve your goal
Here is your `custom.xml`

```
 <CheckBox
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:button="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
   />
```

Just use the `custom.xml` in place of `simple_list_item_single_choice.xml` in your code.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you Tanmay, its working, i placed the radio button left side, but the problem which i faced is the radio button and the text in list view both are merged together.i want to separate both the radio button and the strings in list view. is this possible to do..??

Comment: Opps...!!This happens due  to the `android:paddingLeft="6dip"`..Just remove it and please let me know the result.

Comment: Yeah man,you are great.I accept your answet, its working fine. But now, list view onclick listener will not functioning...why this happened..???

Comment: As you using a `ListView`, you must use `setOnItemClickListener` instead of `setOnClickListener` and use `onItemClick` ,`onClick` dont have any effect on `ListView`..Hope this will help you

Comment: Yeah, i am using OnItemClickListener, but after i did custom radio button for list view, the listener will not functioning.whenever i click the list view, only Radio button puts green on. there is nothing will happen in list view on click. pls let me where i did a mistake.

Comment: Use an attribute like on your list item
`android:focusable="false"`

Comment: where should i place this `android:focusable="false"`. in list view or in custom checkbox..???

Comment: Place it in your `ListView` .

Comment: sorry, its not working. i placed the  android:focusable="false" in list view. but still its not working. is that to do any radio box on click listener..like that..??

Comment: Can you please show me your code.the list view as well as the adapter,if you dont have any problem.So that I can help you.

Comment: At the same time whenever i give `simple_list_item_single_choice` in list view, onItemClicklistener is working, when i give custom radio box, the listener will not be functioning. what i made a mistake..?? pls guide me.

Comment: `list_view.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(jokedescription.this,R.layout.custom,obj.list_array));` this is my list view adapter. i given name custom for customize check box. where i made a mistake.??

Comment: No no.here is not a mistake..Let me help you.

Comment: Are you comfortable with  custom  Adapter?

Comment: Yes, i am not very much familiar.. why?? why my onItemclick is not working..??

Comment: You need to create a custom adapter for that .Use the tutorial http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/Planets.zip

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, by default the radio button is on the right. If you want it on the left then you should grab the sources for simple_list_item_single_choice.xml layout from the SDK and make the appropriate changes, then use this custom layout instead of the default one.

Answer (score 0):

simple_list_item_single_choice use CheckedTextView class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2008 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
/>
```

CheckedTextView class is android.widget package.

This Class source below.

/*

```
 * Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package android.widget;

import com.android.internal.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.ViewDebug;
import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent;


/**
 * An extension to TextView that supports the {@link android.widget.Checkable} interface.
 * This is useful when used in a {@link android.widget.ListView ListView} where the it's 
 * {@link android.widget.ListView#setChoiceMode(int) setChoiceMode} has been set to
 * something other than {@link android.widget.ListView#CHOICE_MODE_NONE CHOICE_MODE_NONE}.
 *
 */
public class CheckedTextView extends TextView implements Checkable {
    private boolean mChecked;
    private int mCheckMarkResource;
    private Drawable mCheckMarkDrawable;
    private int mBasePaddingRight;
    private int mCheckMarkWidth;

    private static final int[] CHECKED_STATE_SET = {
        R.attr.state_checked
    };

    public CheckedTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public CheckedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CheckedTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.CheckedTextView, defStyle, 0);

        Drawable d = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.CheckedTextView_checkMark);
        if (d != null) {
            setCheckMarkDrawable(d);
        }

        boolean checked = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.CheckedTextView_checked, false);
        setChecked(checked);

        a.recycle();
    }

    public void toggle() {
        setChecked(!mChecked);
    }

    @ViewDebug.ExportedProperty
    public boolean isChecked() {
        return mChecked;
    }

    /**
     * <p>Changes the checked state of this text view.</p>
     *
     * @param checked true to check the text, false to uncheck it
     */
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
        if (mChecked != checked) {
            mChecked = checked;
            refreshDrawableState();
        }
    }


    /**
     * Set the checkmark to a given Drawable, identified by its resourece id. This will be drawn
     * when {@link #isChecked()} is true.
     * 
     * @param resid The Drawable to use for the checkmark.
     */
    public void setCheckMarkDrawable(int resid) {
        if (resid != 0 && resid == mCheckMarkResource) {
            return;
        }

        mCheckMarkResource = resid;

        Drawable d = null;
        if (mCheckMarkResource != 0) {
            d = getResources().getDrawable(mCheckMarkResource);
        }
        setCheckMarkDrawable(d);
    }

    /**
     * Set the checkmark to a given Drawable. This will be drawn when {@link #isChecked()} is true.
     *
     * @param d The Drawable to use for the checkmark.
     */
    public void setCheckMarkDrawable(Drawable d) {
        if (mCheckMarkDrawable != null) {
            mCheckMarkDrawable.setCallback(null);
            unscheduleDrawable(mCheckMarkDrawable);
        }
        if (d != null) {
            d.setCallback(this);
            d.setVisible(getVisibility() == VISIBLE, false);
            d.setState(CHECKED_STATE_SET);
            setMinHeight(d.getIntrinsicHeight());

            mCheckMarkWidth = d.getIntrinsicWidth();
            mPaddingRight = mCheckMarkWidth + mBasePaddingRight;
            d.setState(getDrawableState());
        } else {
            mPaddingRight = mBasePaddingRight;
        }
        mCheckMarkDrawable = d;
        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public void setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
        mBasePaddingRight = mPaddingRight;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        final Drawable checkMarkDrawable = mCheckMarkDrawable;
        if (checkMarkDrawable != null) {
            final int verticalGravity = getGravity() & Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK;
            final int height = checkMarkDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

            int y = 0;

            switch (verticalGravity) {
                case Gravity.BOTTOM:
                    y = getHeight() - height;
                    break;
                case Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL:
                    y = (getHeight() - height) / 2;
                    break;
            }

            int right = getWidth();
            checkMarkDrawable.setBounds(
                    right - mCheckMarkWidth - mBasePaddingRight, 
                    y, 
                    right - mBasePaddingRight, 
                    y + height);
            checkMarkDrawable.draw(canvas);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {
        final int[] drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
        if (isChecked()) {
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, CHECKED_STATE_SET);
        }
        return drawableState;
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawableStateChanged() {
        super.drawableStateChanged();

        if (mCheckMarkDrawable != null) {
            int[] myDrawableState = getDrawableState();

            // Set the state of the Drawable
            mCheckMarkDrawable.setState(myDrawableState);

            invalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
        boolean populated = super.dispatchPopulateAccessibilityEvent(event);
        if (!populated) {
            event.setChecked(mChecked);
        }
        return populated;
    }
}
```

You are onDraw modify. and simple_list_item_single_choice.xml modify.

ex.

```
<**your class(modifyed CheckedTextView)** xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"
    android:paddingLeft="6dip"
    android:paddingRight="6dip"
/>
```