# Display whole content of listview item

Tags: android, listview, listviewitem

Here I want to display `whole content of the listview item` on the `listview`. How can I achive this?

```
  ArrayAdapter< String> myadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,answers);
     listview.setAdapter(myadapter);
     listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Main.xml

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/questions_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" >
</ListView>
```

Check the image:

[image: Image of the listview]

Thank you.

**EDIT :**

custom listview with checkbox / RadioButton. I got this but I need the single selection for that.

I try using this `lstvw.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);` but it not works for me.

main.java

```
  private ImageAdapter  adapter; 

private static String month[] = {"January","February","March","April","May",  
    "June","July","August","September",  
    "October","November","December"};  


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ListView lstvw = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

     adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, month);  
     lstvw.setAdapter(adapter);  
      lstvw.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

     lstvw.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}
```

I have no idea for the how to add code for the checkbox into the adapter class.please check the adapter class as below.

ImageAdapter.class

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

public String title[];  
public String description[];  
public Activity context;  
public LayoutInflater inflater;

public ImageAdapter(Activity context,String[] title) {  
    super();  

    this.context = context;  
    this.title = title;  

    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
}  

@Override  
public int getCount() {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return title.length;  
}  

@Override  
public Object getItem(int position) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return null;  
}  

@Override  
public long getItemId(int position) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    return 0;  
}  

public static class ViewHolder  
{  

    TextView txtViewTitle;  
    RadioButton radiobtn;

}  

@Override  
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

    ViewHolder holder;  
    if(convertView==null)  
    {  
        holder = new ViewHolder();  
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);  

        holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lstvw_textView);  

         holder.radiobtn = (RadioButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemradio);

        convertView.setTag(holder);  
    }  
    else  
        holder=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();  

    holder.txtViewTitle.setText(title[position]);  

    /* holder.radiobtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) v;
            if (rb.isChecked() == true) 
            {
                // Here you will get list of checked item.

            }

            else 
           {
            // Here you will get list of unchecked item.    
            }

        }

    }); */

    return convertView;  
}   

}
```

Listitem.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lstvw_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/itemCheckBox"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="hello world" />



<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/itemCheckBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="right" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question

[android listview item height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243894/android-listview-item-height)

wrap_content in the ListView won't do nothing, as the height that matters here is the one from the item.

Comment: Thanks, But I Have tried  `android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"` for the listview but it's not working for mw.

Comment: yes, because it is not to be put in the listView, rather in the item view

Comment: But, I have no item view for the listview, it's simple listview.

Comment: as mentionned in the question i refered to, the item you are using (android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice) is using a fixed height. You need to define your own and define a specific height (that can be wrap_content)

Comment: But into custom listview with radio button with `single selection` I face some problems, Pls check my updated code.Here I got listview with radio button, but problem is single selection.

Comment: for that I am refer this link : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7740740/1584610 but Confuse into `getview` method.

Comment: android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice uses a CheckedTextView with this android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorSingle"  checkmark. I recommand you use the same layout (search for the complete xml of this layout), but simply change the layout_height parameter)

Comment: sorry, I don't get the idea. I am new to android, Please provide explain me using some code...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16222/discussion-between-njzk2-and-android)

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"` :)

Answer (score 0):

Please change it to this and check if you still have any issue...

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/questions_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" >
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the custom list item layout for the listview. You cannot do with that default List Item `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice`

Comment: Using custom listview I have a problem with the `single choice` listview with radio button.

Comment: what is the problem with custom list view?

Comment: I have problem with the single select item.

Comment: You can do the single select item in custom list view also

Comment: see this link. It will help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775886/radio-button-in-list-view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740614/android-radio-button-in-listview

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16191/discussion-between-android-and-coder-decoder-encoder)

Comment: Please check my updated code for the custom listview with radio button. I got the success, but I want to `single selection`.

Comment: Your adapter is correct only. What error actually you getting?

Comment: I have no error Occurred,But I want to add some code for the `single selection`.How can I do this?, I don't get the idea. Me refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7740740/1584610