# How to display the full content of each item in ListView (Android Studio)?

Tags: android-listview

I am trying to display the entire content of each item in `ListView`. I read other posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243894/android-listview-item-height))([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245258/display-whole-content-of-listview-item)), but none of them worked.

Things I tried so far:

(1) I added `android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"` to `TextView`

(2) Just in case, I added `android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"` to `ListView`

(3) I added `android:height=wrap_content` to `TextView`

(4) I added `android:height=wrap_content` to to `ListView`

(5) I added (1) and (3)

(6) I added (2) and (4)

(7) I added `convertView.setMinimumHeight(100);` in my java file

Here is my file with `ListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".FragmentNotes"
    android:theme="@style/FontStyle"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_note_id">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/white_background_round"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/white_background_round" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/white_background_round"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_string"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Notes"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="45sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/title_image"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/title_string"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/title_string"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/title_string"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_note_english" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button_background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/white_background_round"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/white_background_round"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:background="@drawable/light_background_round_english" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_my_notes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_background"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button_background"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_background"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/centerline"
            android:text="My Notes"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:elevation="10dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_all_notes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_background"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_background"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_background"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/centerline"
            android:text="All Notes"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:elevation="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/centerline"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_background"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_background"/>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/white_background_round"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/white_background_round"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/white_background_round"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button_background"
            android:layout_margin="10sp"
            android:id="@+id/list_view" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/white_background_round"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/white_background_round"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And here is my file with `TextView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview_item_text"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:text="1) When anyone brings a grain offering to the Lord, their offering is to be of the finest flour. They are to pour olive oil on it, put incense on it"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20sp"
    android:paddingRight="20sp"
    android:paddingTop="10sp"
    android:paddingBottom="10sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.5"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the Java code for this as well? Seems like the problem could be in your Java code.

Comment: @RishabhBhatia Thank you for your comment. I found that the problem was the `TextView`'s line `singleLine="true". I truly appreciate your willingness to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone needs this answer, I found that the problem was `TextView`'s line `android:singleLine="true"`. I removed the line, and now I can see all contents for each item in `ListView`.